# Parallel Linq Optimization with SelectMany

Tags: .net, plinq, npoi

I'm scanning and transforming several hundred thousand Excel workbooks each with variable number of worksheets. I'm taking a PLINQ query on the array of workbook file names, opening each workbook using NPOI, enumerating the worksheets, flattening the enumerable and transforming each worksheet.

```
var first = GetFilesAsArray().AsParallel();
var second = first.Select(f => OpenWorkbook(f)); // Sometimes expensive
var third = second.SelectMany(w => Enumerable.Range(0, w.NumberOfSheets).Select(i => w.GetSheetAt(i));
var fourth = third.Select(s => ExpensiveTransformation(s)); // Always expensive
```

Early on this threads well, upwards of all 32 cores but later on it falls to 1 or 2 cores. I'm debating whether I might gain more efficiency from bringing the sheet transformation inside the inner single-threaded SelectMany query keeping the multi-threading to the workbook outside Select query.

```
var first = GetFilesAsArray();
var second = first.Select(f => OpenWorkbook(f)).AsParallel(); // Sometimes expensive
var third = second.SelectMany(w => Enumerable.Range(0, w.NumberOfSheets).Select(i => ExpensiveTransformation(w.GetSheetAt(i))); // Always expensive
```

I might be a little greedy hoping to thread the workbooks and the sheets.

Comment: Well, why don't you try it both ways and use whichever is faster? And do you actually have a question?

Comment: 1 to 2 weeks is a long test so before I commit the resources I'm curious to see if anyone has any advice for the AsParallel with the SelectMany and where best to place the AsParallel.

Comment: With performance, it's always best to test it yourself. You don't need to do this for all your data, just measure a representative sample.

Comment: Unfortunately the representative sample proved not to reflect the long term outcome as stated that early on it parallelized well and I was happy with performance but later on after about 2 days the performance diminished greatly. I'm also curious what might be the cause there.